# Upgrading Java version on a desktop application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a Java Desktop Application that currently uses Java 6. The app is deployed using Java Web Start and JNLP along with an installer. Also, the application is a Maven based project.

I want to upgrade to Java 8 and I was wondering what are the implications of this kind of change to the infrastructure? (I was thinking that I have to change the Java version in the installer and also deploy an update for the current users).

P.S. The application works on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X

Comment: You might get more specific help if you show (relevant parts of) your jnlp file so one might see e.g. if it is tied to a specific java version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is backward compatible so you don't have to worry about code getting broken when upgrading to Java 8 runtime

As per infrastructure change, you have to change in pom.xml   configuration tag to

```
<configuration>
       <source>1.8</source>
       <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

and in your build path change the target runtime to installed JDK 8 version in your IDE and and in your jnlp file you have to mentioned j2se  version as

like so

```
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.8+"
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="<your signed app jar>"
        main="true" />

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This maybe will have a lot of conflict of Java 6 and Java 8, since hava 6 released in 2006. But it depends on your logic code how it looks like. In IDE IntelliJ there could use the Java 8 and configure it compatible with Java 6. If you are ready for update your Java 6 to Java 8 you also need to prepare to refactor your code.

The JDK released details below.

> JDK 1.6 | Code Name : Mustang | Year : 2006
>
> 1. Scripting Language Support
> 2. JDBC 4.0 support
> 3. Java Compiler API
> 4. Pluggable Annotations
> 5. Native PKI, Java GSS, Kerberos and LDAP support
> 6. Integrated Web Services
> 7. Light weight
>
> JDK 1.7 | Code Name : Dolphin | Year : 2011
>
> 1. Automated Resource Management
> 2. Timsort is used to sort collections and arrays of objects instead of merge sort
> 3. Multiple exceptions handling in single catch block
> 4. String in switch
> 5. JDBC 4.1 support
> 6. JVM Enhancements(invokedynamic instructions)
> 7. Automatic Type Inference during the Generic Instance Creation(using diamond operator)
> 8. Numeric literals with underscore
> 9. Fork and Join Framework
> 10. G1 Garbage Collector
>
> JDK 1.8 | Code Name : Spider | Year : 2014
>
> 1. Lambda Expression
> 2. Streams
> 3. Functional Interface
> 4. Nashorn
> 5. Performance Improvement for HashMaps with Key Collisions
> 6. Parallel Array Sorting
> 7. Stringjoiner class
> 8. Optional Class
> 9. Remove permanent generation
> 10. Annotation on Java Types